# Beginner question about why a certain function does not change the value of the original list (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I've been working to learn coding and just came across the fact that python stores variables set equal to each other (e.g. nums = nums_copy) in the same location, so if you change one, you change the other (please correct me if I'm wrong).

So I saw this example of a function and was wondering why it doesnt change the original list?

```
def delete_starting_evens(lst):
  while (len(lst) > 0 and lst[0] % 2 == 0):
    lst = lst[1:]
  return lst

my_list = [4, 8, 10]
print(delete_starting_evens(my_list), my_list)
```

output:

```
[] [4, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 3):

You never operate on the original list.  In each loop iteration, you create a new list (`lst[1:]`) derived from the previous value, and then assign that to your local variable `lst`.

If you want to change the original list, then use list-altering methods, such as

```
lst.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're printing 2 variables , the first one is the return of your function and then my_list which is [4, 8, 10]

Answer (score 0):

`lst` is local variable. When you assign to it, you simply change what the variable refers to; it has no effect the argument that was previously bound to the name.

If you want to drop all the leading even numbers, you can use `del`:

```
def delete_starting_evens(lst):
    while lst and lst[0] % 2 == 0:
        del lst[0]
```

You don't need to return the list, as both `lst` and `my_list` refer to the same list, so any changes made via `lst` are visible from `my_list` as well.

Answer (score 0):

As some users said you need to operate directly on the list not assign it, you can also use the keyword `is` to check if two variables have the same id:

```
def delete_starting_evens(lst):
    while len(lst) > 0 and not lst[0] % 2:
        lst.pop(0)

    return lst


my_list = [4, 8, 10]
print(delete_starting_evens(my_list) is my_list)
```

**outup**

```
True
```

Comment: Oh cool! I will definitely be using that to play around with